# trac rich client

Tags: trac

My company uses trac for bug tracking, and while it works fine, I find the web interface a bit clunky, particularly when it comes to sorting and quickly switching between tickets.

Are there any rich client interfaces or maybe Eclipse plugins?  I've seen the mylyn connector but that seems to just allow you to basically use the webpage within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is an XML RPC plugin that you can use to interact with a Trac server using remote scripts.  If there is something in particular that you want to do, you may be able to script it up with Ruby, Python, or a number of other languages.  There are a number of examples on the plugin's web site: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm looking for more of a whole rich interface, though it doesn't seem like one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever looked at [FatBug](http://www.fat-bug.com/) for Trac.  It is a rich client for Trac.  It has a nice snipping tool for uploading images directly into Trac and full text searching of all of the tickets in Trac. It even supports offline mode for being able to work with tickets when you do not have access to the Internet.

Comment: I had not seen that but we've since switches to Jira. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that the FatBug client has now become free. If anyone is still using Trac, this is a nice piece of software.